# How to search a a directory tree in TCL for files that end in .so or .a and build a list of those directories

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to write a set of TCL scripts that helps setup a user's environment for a set of libraries that are not in their standard `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as part of a support solution.

Since the system is rather sparse in terms of what I can install, I don't really have access to any TCL extensions and am trying to do this in base TCL as much as possible. I'm also relatively new to TCL as a language.

What I'd like to do is search through a directory structure and locate the directories that have `.so` and `.a` files in them, build a list of those, and, eventually add them to the user's `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

If I were doing this in a shell, I'd just use find with something like this:

```
find /dir -type f \( -name "*.so" -o -name "*.a" \) | awk -F/ 'sub(FS $NF,x)' | sort -u
```

I could hard-code the paths, but we want a single set of scripts that can manage several different applications.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @glennjackman That's in TCL? Looking through the documentation on the TCL/TK website doesn't turn up a find command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/home) has a [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) module that does a recursive find:

```
package require fileutil
set filenames [::fileutil::findByPattern /dir -glob {*.so *.a}]
foreach filename $filenames {
    if {[file isfile $filename]} {
        set dirs([file dirname $filename]) 1
    }
}
puts [array names dirs]
```

If you want to use this, but can't install something, you can just take the procedures and add them to your code (with the appropriate attribution) -- http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/dir?ci=63d99a74f4600441&name=modules/fileutil

Otherwise, just call the system's `find` command and parse the output (assume that your filenames do not contain newlines).

```
set filenames [split [exec find /dir -type f ( -name *.so -o -name *.a )] \n]
```

And the loop to extract the unique directories is similar. As a side benefit, the `find` invocation is actually easier to read because you don't have to escape all the chars that are special to the shell.

Comment: I was hoping to do it all in TCL, but I think I'll implement the exec option for now until I understand more about fileutil.

Thanks a lot!